# Get a calculated price of Product Variation

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I created a promotion with offer type - `Fixed amount off each matching product` and applies to - `Specific product`. In my custom block I get the product entity, but don't see any promotions there. How can I get it?

UPD: Tried to solve this problem with via `commerce_order.price_calculator` service.

```
commercePriceCalc = \Drupal::service('commerce_order.price_calculator');
$context = new Context(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load(1), 
                     \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_store')->load(1));
$prices = $commercePriceCalc->calculate($slide->field_product->entity, 1, $context);
```

So, `calculate` method returns me a `PriceCalculatorResult` object with 2 properties, `calculatedPrice` and `basePrice` but they are identical, as if the discount didn't apply, but I see it applied in a cart.

Comment: I haven't had to do this. But the official docs suggest using a different service: commerce_price.chain_price_resolver. Source: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/adapting-from-1x/price-calculation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've already solved this issue, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem, by passing the 4th argument `$adjustment_types` to the `$commercePriceCalc->calculate` method.

```
$adjustment_types = array("promotion" => "promotion");
```

So, the final version of the code

```
$commercePriceCalc = \Drupal::service('commerce_order.price_calculator');
$context = new Context(\Drupal::currentUser(), 
                     \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_store')->load($store_id));
$prices = $commercePriceCalc->calculate($slide->field_product->entity, 1, $context, $adjustment_types);
```